# How to send back data from multiple auto-generated fields from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an application which allows users to go trough a series of questions and select their response from 4 pre-determined options. The problem I'm facing is how to send data back to the controller. I have an object `Game` which holds a property `Questions` while each question holds a `Code`, `Question` and `Answer`, all `string` type.

I've created a page which displays every question and the answer in a dropdownlist (once I figure out how to place it as radiobuttons, I'll use that), but I'm stumped as to how I should send the results back to the controller: every `select` element in the generated `HTML` code has the same `id`, so how can I distinguish a question-answer relationship from any other?

Are there alternative approaches that would be better? I've tried working with a `PartialView` for each question, but if possible I'd like to stick to one page with a list of questions.

The code I'm using to create my current view is this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Game", FormMethod.Post)) {
        foreach (var question in Model.Questions) {
            <div class="question">
                <h4>@vraag.Vraag</h4>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => question.Code, new SelectList(question .Answers))
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => question.Code)            
            </div>
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
```

I want to send all answers back to my controller in a way that clearly tells me which answer is meant for what question's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `foreach` to bind lists because their name fields won't be indexed (so model binder doesn't know what to do with them). You need to use a `for` loop. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++) {
        <div class="question">
            <h4>@vraag.Vraag</h4>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Questions[i].Code, new SelectList(Model.Questions[i].Answers))
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Questions[i].Code)            
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll try it out and see where it brings me.

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted, thanks! I have noticed an additional fault though: the value of my hidden field always stays the same (for the two current questions, it has values 1 and 3). How come this value doesn't change when I select another answer?

Comment: No problems! Glad I could help. You'll need to call `ModelState.Clear` in your `HttpPost` method before using the Model. By default MVC will use the model values that you passed the view (located in `ModelState`).